# Interstitial ad in android - Gradle configuration

Tags: android, gradle, ads, interstitial

I want to insert interstitial ad in Android Studio. All the confusion started when I came to know that we need the below line for inserting ads

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
```

(I Don't know where google guys came up with that number. Not sure how to find that number)

Now, I have no idea what the below configuration should be for my project

**compileSdkVersion 23

buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'**

I tried all versions from 21 onwards but I end up with some error when I sync gradle

Can anyone please point me what exactly are the step by step configurations I need to set up my interstitial ad. I don't want interstitial code. I want setup instructions to make interstitial ad work.

I have gone through google without much help
Please help !

Thanks!

Comment: if you don't know exact number of library then add library from project structure using menu.

Comment: First Google then SO if you want to know how to set up Interstitial Ads. What Gradle error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing compileSdkVersion to 23 solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Update Google play from sdk.

then,

Goto File> Project Structure > App > Write google play in text field. You will have current google play services in list. select that from there. Press Apply.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cool article about the gradle setup: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/android/quick-start#configure_gradle

I think you have to add this `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'`, instead of this `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'` to the gradle.

And you also have to add this to the `strings.xml`: `<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">/6499/example/banner</string>`

Comment: I followed exactly the same setup instructions as mentioned in the above site. No where in that site its mentioned about the issues we might encounter.